# PHP update MYSQL Form not working

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to edit the lastname (lname) but its not working ,

im getting this error :

> ERROR: Could not able to execute UPDATE tablename SET fname = '',
>   lname = '' WHERE fname = . You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("IP","DB","PASS (hiden ofc)", "DBN");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt update query execution
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET fname = '$nfname', lname = '$nlname' WHERE fname = $fname";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Records were updated successfully.";
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

--- HTML CODE ---

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test editing </h1>
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
OrginalFirstname: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br><br>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br><br>
NewFirstname: <input type="text" name="nfname" /><br><br>
 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you updating all the fields if you only want to edit the last name? Where are those variables assigned?

Comment: This is just done for testing purpose , im kinda new to it

Comment: Is that your entire code?

Comment: Only update fields that need to be updated. You also should use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to put apostrophes on the last part of your query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tablename SET fname = '$nfname', lname = '$nlname' WHERE fname = '$fname'";
```

This should work.

Make sure you escaped all the variables with `mysqli_real_escape_string`. If one of the variables has a non-escaped apostrophe, the query will fail again.

If the PHP code in your question is the entire code, then you are not getting the values from the `$_POST[]`.

You can get the values into your variables using `extract($_POST);` on the beggining of your code.

Comment: I think that's the issue he isn't assigning the variables which he is using.

Comment: Aaaah i didnt know i had to add it all seems to be working currently  Thank you very much! and sorry for my mistakes